# Facebook access token for current 2.1 api version

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token

So i'm developing an app where I need to get posts from a certain facebook group.
I obtain the access tokens with the Javascript SDK, and made all the API calls server-side using that token.

Now I need to update the app to the API v2.1, problem is that the **Javascript SDK returns a token that only calls API v2.0.**

In the Graph API Explorer, when i "GET" a certain post, lets say "1483618775203669_1513925692172977" specifically for the v2.1, with the token returned from the Javascript SDK, it calls the v2.0 API, but with the Access Token **automatically generated** by facebook, it calls the 2.1 API

I've changed the javascript configuration to specify the 2.1 API as it follows

```
FB.init({
 appId: '529974393756xxx',
 xfbml: true,
 version: 'v2.1'
});
```

But it stills returning the "2.0 only token".

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to specify which api to use when getting "1483618775203669_1513925692172977" otherwise it will fallback to the oldest version you are allowed to use